# Can't get webpack to load in Index.cshtml

Tags: node.js, asp.net-core, webpack

I'm on a React project and I'm making it as an asp.Net Core-application. I'm aware of webpack to bundle files, in my case I need to get some jsx-files bundled. I have looked through some guides and tutorials on [ReactJS.Net's own site](https://reactjs.net/guides/webpack.html) and [this Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w5TupxbnnrM) etc. What I have so far is my index file `Index.cshtml`:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello React</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/remarkable/1.7.1/remarkable.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And then made a package.json through the `npm init`-command in node.js with all the default props except the name:

```
{
  "name": "marck",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "babel": "babel",
    "webpack": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.20.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.9",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0"
  }
}
```

Created a `webpack.config.js`-file:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './app.jsx',
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
};
```

And finally I have created the `app.jsx`-file I want to get bundled in webpack, and it's the code from the example on ReactJS.Net:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

var CommentBox = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
          <div className="commentBox">
            Hello, world! I am a CommentBox.
          </div>
      );
    }
});
ReactDOM.render(
  <CommentBox />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

When I run webpack in node.js command prompt it says:

```
    Assets   Size   Chunks           Chunk Names
bundle.js   740 kb       0 [emitted] main
    + 179 hidden modules
```

So it looks like it bundles something or am I wrong?
When I try run it, it gives me this GET-error in the browser

`GET http://localhost:9217/bundle.js`

And this:

```
    [15:22:51 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time)] Browser Link: Failed to invoke return value callback:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of null
```

My folders are set as follows:

```
Solution 'webpack'
>Solution Items
>src
  >webpack
  >wwwroot
  >Dependencies
  >Controllers
  >Views
    >Home
      Index.cshtml
  app.config
  app.jsx
  appsettings.json
  bundle.js
  package.json
  program.cs
  >project.json
  Startup.cs
  web.config
  webpack.config.js
```

I hope some of you can tell me what I need to do to get this to work, because I think that the documentation and the guides aren't that clear all the time. Everybody shows different ways to do it, and I'm kind of confused now.

**EDIT:**

I've found out, that the applikation only looks in the `wwwroot`-folder when it's an asp.Net Core applikation, so I tried to put the `bundle.js`-file in that folder and then changed the direction in my `Index.cshtml`-file to that and then it worked. I hope this will help others :)